# Color.RGBToHSV Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to float[]

Tags: java, android, arrays, colors, rgb

Using the ADT

```
import android.graphics.Color;
```

I keep getting a `Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to float[]`.

```
float[] hsv = new float[3];

hsv = Color.RGBToHSV(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], hsv);
```

Error line highlights under `Color.RGBToHSV(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], hsv);` and reads `type mismatch`. Is there anyway around this? This code was previously setup for JRE but I am converting it to ADT.

previously it read;

```
hsv = java.awt.Color.RGBtoHSB(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], hsv);
```

How can I correct this type mismatch?

I have tried this way, but I need it to be added to `float[] hsv` array;

```
Color.RGBToHSV(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], hsv);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: java.awt.Color.RGBtoHSB is type float[] and android.graphics.Color.RGBToHSV is type void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from the android source code

```
public static void RGBToHSV(int red, int green, int blue, float hsv[]) {
    if (hsv.length < 3) {
        throw new RuntimeException("3 components required for hsv");
    }
    nativeRGBToHSV(red, green, blue, hsv);
}
```

Which means it converts the RGB colors to HSV, and puts them in the array. The method doesn't return anything, contrary to the `java.awt.Color` source code

```
public static float[] RGBtoHSB(int r, int g, int b, float[] hsbvals) {
    float hue, saturation, brightness;
    if (hsbvals == null) {
        hsbvals = new float[3];
    }
    int cmax = (r > g) ? r : g;
    if (b > cmax) cmax = b;
    int cmin = (r < g) ? r : g;
    if (b < cmin) cmin = b;

    brightness = ((float) cmax) / 255.0f;
    if (cmax != 0)
        saturation = ((float) (cmax - cmin)) / ((float) cmax);
    else
        saturation = 0;
    if (saturation == 0)
        hue = 0;
    else {
        float redc = ((float) (cmax - r)) / ((float) (cmax - cmin));
        float greenc = ((float) (cmax - g)) / ((float) (cmax - cmin));
        float bluec = ((float) (cmax - b)) / ((float) (cmax - cmin));
        if (r == cmax)
            hue = bluec - greenc;
        else if (g == cmax)
            hue = 2.0f + redc - bluec;
        else
            hue = 4.0f + greenc - redc;
        hue = hue / 6.0f;
        if (hue < 0)
            hue = hue + 1.0f;
    }
    hsbvals[0] = hue;
    hsbvals[1] = saturation;
    hsbvals[2] = brightness;
    return hsbvals;
}
```

The return types are different. `float[]` vs `void`

Answer (score 0):

It puts those values in an array you're passing as an argument. So its return value type is actually `void`.

Comment: Color.RGBToHSV(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2], hsv); is not going to be added to the array in my understanding. I need to find a way to add those values to hsv